# Using github.inputs and variables in workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

So basically what I try to do is as following

if there is a push to repository A trigger the pipeline of repository B with an input thatis the the name of the branch in repository A that is pushed to. Lets call it $branchname

So what I did was a bit googling and saw that I need to add a workflow_dispatch in the B's workflow file and add some inputs. That work nice. But...

I still want people to be able to push to repository B from branches in B and trigger its pipeline with $branchname equal to a value of "dev".

I did the following in

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
       uses: ...
          ....
       - name: my script
         run: |
           if [[ -v ${{ inputs.branchname }} ]]; then value=${{ inputs.branchname }};else value="dev"; fi
           ...
```

But in the code above the value of branchname is empty for pushes from repository B. Since ${{ inputs.branchname }} is empty.  So i need to find a way to be able to map the workflow_dispatch variable to a env variable to be able to use it regardless if the push is in repo A or repo B.

Do you know any way?
Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by:

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
       uses: ...
          ....
       - name: my script
         run: |
           my__first_var=${{ inputs.branchname }}
           if [[ -v my_var ]];
              my_second_var="$my__first_var"
           else
              my_second_var="dev"
           fi
           ...
```